# why doesn't john work on an unshadow file

Tags: john-the-ripper

I was trying to unshadow my passwd and shadow file on the new version of john. However, every time I try to use john to decrypt the hash it throws an error.

```
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

But if I go to take a look at the file, I find my hashes there. Is this happening because the hash begins with `root:$y$` instead of the normal hash identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this. The $y$ represents yescrypt which and be decrypted by john if the following command is used:

```
john --format=crypt filename
```